# waitfor problem in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
while 1 = 1     
  begin         
   waitfor time @timeToRun         
   begin             
     /*delete some records from table X*/        
   end     
  end
```

In the codes above, will the SQL server lock the table X during the wait? I would
like to insert records into table X during this wait time. Is it possible?

Comment: @mitch-wheat Thanks. During the waiting time, I would like to delete the records in table X that are older than two weeks. At the same time, the new data will be inserted into this table. This interval of the waiting time is about one week. The version is SQL Server 2008 express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All write operations acquire X locks on the rows being updated (deleted) and all these X locks will be hold until the transaction commits. Every statement creates an implicit transaction that commits automatically at the end of the statement, if no transaction is explicitly specified.

So the answer to your question depends whether you call this in a context of an existing transaction or not. If not, then (assuming you do not start a transaction in the inner begin... end block and leave the transaction open) then no lock will be held. If the code is run in a the context of an existing transaction (eg. a `TransactionScope` in the client started automatically by the WCF service behavior) then any lock placed by the delete will be hold while you wait, until the transaction is committed..

Comment: The insertion happens in another transaction. and the insertion happens very frequently. This while block is for deleting older data regularly.

Comment: You don't need to wait, technically. All those inserts that are blocked during the delete are guaranteed to be allowed ahead of the next delete (ie. the delete cannot starve inserts). Note that proper clustered index choice should avoid this problem altogether, as the deletes (periodic Cleanup) should not overlap the range where inserts occur so they should not contend for locks.

Comment: I think I didn't state my problem clearly. Actually, I want to delete the old data once a week, so I use waitfor to schedule my job. I don't want to use the job scheduler of SQL server and windows.

Comment: Instead of lingering in a session for one week, Why not use a timer and activation? This is totally constrained within the DB and does not require SQL agent nor windows scheduler. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx

Comment: If you waitfor one week, what guarantees that you'be doing the cleanup if the session is ever killed (eg. server restart)?

Comment: Could you advise how to start a timer when a server restarts?

Answer (score 0):

Two part question:
1) In the codes above, will the SQL server lock the table X during the wait?
**No.  It may lock the rows, but not the table.**

2) I would like to insert records into table X during this wait time. Is it possible?
**Yes, but they will be locked until your commit**

**Note:** you will want to wrap any work you are doing in a transaction with a BEGIN/COMMIT block.  This will avoid the locking issue entirely.

Comment: So can I insert records during the waiting time?

Comment: Sure, just BEGIN/COMMIT then as well.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to commit after each insertion?

Comment: Just around each group of insert; for example, BEGIN, 10 INSERTS, COMMIT; Not 10 sets of BEGIN INSERT COMMIT